# Fuzzy match in sharepoint search engine?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

In sharepoint 2007 sites, we can search for people or other contents. Is the search engine able to do fuzzy match so that "Micheal" can be corrected to "Michael"? If it's possible, does it need extra configuration?

I am also writing a custom webpart that uses sharepoint search service, a web service that has url like "http://site/_vti_bin/search.asm". Is it possible to use this service to do fuzzy search as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Search Summary Web Part provides that capability: try searching SharePoint for "Microsfot"  and you'll get a "Did you mean ***Microsoft***?" prompt. However, I only seem to see it when I get no results at all, and it looks like it has some other limitations:

[Threewill Wiki (posted by Kirk Liemohn)](http://wiki.threewill.com/display/enterprise/Search+Summary+Web+Part+-+Did+You+Mean)

I haven't seen that kind of matching used specifically, but you might get some ideas from the [wildcard](http://wildcardsearch.codeplex.com/Wikipage) search web part on codeplex.